# How to pass request content with HttpClient GetAsync method in c#

Tags: c#

How do I pass request content in the `HttpClient.GetAsync` method? I need to fetch data depending upon request content.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> QuickSearch()
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            HttpResponseMessage response =await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:8080/document/quicksearch");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.Write("Success");
            }
```

Comment: i am connecting from java api to angular ui.

Comment: throw my .Net api

Comment: What is "request content"? Are you asking how to provide a body with a GET request? Because if you are, you shouldn't. GET shouldn't require a body.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using .NET Core, the standard HttpClient can do this out-of-the-box. For example, to send a GET request with a JSON body:

```
HttpClient client = ...

...

var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri("some url"),
    Content = new StringContent("some json", Encoding.UTF8, ContentType.Json),
};

var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: You may use `MediaTypeNames.Application.Json` instead of `ContentType.Json`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send content, then you need to send it as query string (According to your API route)

```
HttpResponseMessage response =await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:8080/document/quicksearch/paramname=<dynamicName>&paramValue=<dynamicValue>");
```

And in API check for "paramName" and "paramValue"

Comment: here the fact is my parameters are not predefined . i have to get a single parameter but the attribute name can be anything so that i can not define it in my model class.i have to get the attribute name and type and pass as query string

Comment: then you need to use PostAsync or send your parameter with name & value . See edited answer

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
 {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri("your url"),
            Content = new StringContent("your json", Encoding.UTF8, ContentType.Json),
        };

        using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
        {
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

**EDITED:**
This is minor different then @SonaliJain answer above: 
`MediaTypeNames.Application.Json` instead of `ContentType.Json`

Comment: please add explanation, especially when answering such an old question

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the existing one with 5 upvotes?

Comment: `MediaTypeNames.Application.Json` instead of `ContentType.Json` and `using` statements

Comment: @Dialecticus this is inside the 'using', with the full HttpClient for people who don't know.

Comment: I usually have `HttpClient` as public static member of some general class. It lives for the whole duration of the app. No need to dispose of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your "request content" would be POST data, no?

If you're sending it using the standard form content way of doing it, you would first have to build the content:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "theperplexedone"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "mypassword123"),
            });
```

And then submit it using `PostAsync` instead:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/document/quicksearch", content);
```

Comment: here the fact is my parameters are not predefined . i have to get a single parameter but the attribute name can be anything so that i can not define it in my model class.i have to get the attribute name and type and pass as query string. and it is for GET

Comment: This might work for PostAsync, but the question is about GetAsync.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thank you for your comments, i got the solution

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> QuickSearch(HttpRequestMessage Query)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

                    Console.WriteLine(Query);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:8080/document/quicksearch/"+ Query.RequestUri.Query);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("Failure");
                    }

                    return response;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }
```