# How to convert sandman request to .net (VB or C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, rest, httprequest

I'm trying to convert and sandman request to VB (or C#) but there is always something that goes wrong.
Can someone tell me how to do this.

Here I the Sandman collection:

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "FA79A60C-A699-45ED-9A3C-67464BF2F474",
        "name": "test",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "https://api.testman.se/request/v42/person-nr?q=190103245566",
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "bearer",
                    "bearer": [
                        {
                            "key": "token",
                            "value": "Bearer 6854DBC2-73AF-4857-9391-F97FEC37779E",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://api.testman.se/request/v42/person-nr?q=190103245566",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "api",
                        "testman.se",
                        "se"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "request",
                        "v42",
                        "person-id"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "q",
                            "value": "190103245566"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried a couple of different suggestions from the web and here is the latest.
But it give error "It is not possible to send content text with this verb type"

And the code for that:

```
    Public Async Sub test()
        Dim _T As New auth
        Dim client As New HttpClient
        Dim RS As Object
        Dim req As New HttpRequestMessage
        Dim Url As String = "https://api.testman.se/request/v42/person-nr?q=190103245566"
        Dim response As New HttpResponseMessage

        _T.bearer.key = "token"
        _T.bearer.type = "string"
        _T.bearer.value = "Bearer 6854DBC2-73AF-4857-9391-F97FEC37779E"
        _T.type = "bearer"

        req.Headers.Clear()
        req.Method = HttpMethod.Get
        req.RequestUri = New Uri(Url)
        req.Content = New StringContent(New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_T), System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

        Try
            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us")
            req.Headers.Add("UA-CPU", "x86")
            req.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")

            response = Await client.SendAsync(req).ConfigureAwait(False)
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim ss As String = ex.Message
        End Try

        Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        'Dim dict As New TDListRequest
        'dict = jss.Deserialize(Of TDListRequest)(_RS)
    End Sub
```

Is there anyone who can give me an idea how to solve this?

Update 2021-05-27.

I install Postman on my computer and it was where easy to setup.
When I do a request in postman it works directly.

I read this in the Postman help about 'Bearer Token':
*"Bearer tokens allow requests to authenticate using an access key, such as a JSON Web Token (JWT). The token is a text string, included in the request header."*
So I think that I have to make some class of my data and key and then then Crypt it in some way and then put it in DefaultRequestHeaders

I'm I on the right way, or?

/Claes

Comment: The message seems clear: a GET request doesn't have Content, just a URL. You will need to send auth-info as headers

Comment: I found this topic before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006372/how-to-pass-request-content-with-httpclient-getasync-method-in-c-sharp.
How do I send all this as Headers?

Comment: You can set headers through [HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders)