# CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from ‘System.Net.Http.HttpContent’ to ‘System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption’

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, httpclient, webapi

I'm trying to make a call to another microservice's get method from a service. But when I try to do so, I'm getting this error:

> CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from ‘System.Net.Http.HttpContent’ to ‘System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption’.

Below is the code in the source microservice to get a list of data from the destination service.

```
this._httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
           .Accept
           .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "relativeAddress");
request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invoiceFilterRequest),
                                            Encoding.UTF8,
                                            "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header

var response = await this._httpClient.GetAsync(InvEndpoints.GET_Cus_List, request.Content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Actual error is shown in the 2nd parameter `request.Content` in the `GetAsync()` call.

Here is the destination service method:

```
[HttpGet("cus/filter")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PagedList<Inv>>> GetCusByFilterAsync(InvFilterRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

Is there any simple solution to send object as a parameter using HTTP GET to another microservice other than sending them as a query string using the above code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass request content with HttpClient GetAsync method in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006372/how-to-pass-request-content-with-httpclient-getasync-method-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [GetAsync(String, HttpCompletionOption) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-5.0), when using the `GetAsync` method, the second parameter should be the `HttpCompletionOption`, instead of `HttpContent`.

From your description, it seems that you want to send a request with parameters, if that is the case, you should use the [`HttpClient.PostAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=net-5.0), instead of the `HttpClient.GetAsync` method, refer the following sample:

```
var companyForCreation = new CompanyForCreationDto
{
    Name = "Eagle IT Ltd.",
    Country = "USA",
    Address    = "Eagle IT Street 289"
};
var company = JsonSerializer.Serialize(companyForCreation);
var requestContent = new StringContent(company, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("companies", requestContent);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var createdCompany = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CompanyDto>(content, _options);
```

Reference: [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Cor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0)